# Hide status and title bar on android titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I am working on titanium project and am facing a problem where when I use `win.open({modal:true});` my application screen does not hide the status bar and title bar in Android devices. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

to hid ethe title bars in your screen just do this in your oncreate before adding the setcontentview.This will hide your title bar

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Correct for pure Android/Java projects, but not very useful for Titanium, which does not provide a binding to that... Is there a way to add a custom Java hook in Titanium?